# Including a ping timeout feature

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have Server A that receive's updates from Server B.  I would like to add functionality to Server A where if it does not receive a message(server B will send update and ping messages) in 1 minutes time, Server A will go into a paused state and wait for messages to come in again.

I was looking into a boost::asio::deadline_timer, but I cannot figure out if it is possible, or if you can run this asynchronously.  I tried a class that runs in its own thread and uses a deadline timer, but I am unable to cancel and restart the deadline timer.  Here is some example code I used for that.

The implementation:

```
void ping_timeout::reset_timer()
{
    ping_timeout_.cancel();
    ping_timeout_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(60));
    //Call to clear the cache of a static class, which is the paused state I would like
    ping_timeout_.async_wait(boost::bind(&cache::empty_cache));
    io_.run();
}
```

I am unable to cancel the deadline timer from my main thread of execution by calling reset timer, I am guessing because io_.run() is waiting for the 60 seconds to expire.

Is there any modification I can do, any any libraries out there that I can us to achieve the results I would like?  Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Edit:

Main Loop:

```
ping_timeout timeout;
boost::thread(boost::bind(&cache::run_io,boost::ref(service)));
while(true)
{
    std::string message = s_recv(subscriber);
    }
    if(message.compare("UPDATE") == 0)
    {
       //Process update 
    }
    else if(message.compare("PING") == 0)
    {
        timeout.reset_timer();
    }
}
```

Edit 2:

Working code:

```
void cache::process_cache()
{
    boost::asio::io_service service;
    boost::asio::io_service::work work(service);
    boost::thread(boost::bind(&cache::run_io,boost::ref(service)));

    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(service,boost::posix_time::seconds(60));
    timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&cache::empty_cache,boost::asio::placeholders::error));

    while(true)
    {
        std::string message = s_recv(subscriber);
        if(message.compare("UPDATE") == 0)
        {
            //Process update 
        }
        else if(message.compare("PING") == 0)
        {
            timer.cancel();
            timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(60));
            timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&cache::empty_cache,boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
    }
}

void cache::empty_cache(const boost::system::error_code& e)
{
    if(e.value() == 0)
    {
        //Clear cache  
    }
}


void cache::run_io(boost::asio::io_service& io)
{
    io.run();
}
```

Comment: Why does `ping_timeout` have its own `io_service` instance ?

Comment: Previous to this feature I was not using any `io_service` objects for my multi-threading, which is why `ping_timeout` has it's own `io_service` instance.  I'm guessing this isn't right, but how should I structure it?

Comment: If you don't have to specifically separate tasks, use 1 central `io_service` instance. Pass it via reference to other classes' instances that need it.

Comment: I can do that, although I don't think it will do much to solve my problem, I am unable to get my program to work with one ping_timeout object, so it is not even matter of having more than one at the moment.

Comment: I think you should show us what your main loop looks like.

Comment: Updated OP with the main loop.  It is very simple, s_recv waits for a message, if the message is UPDATE, the message is processed, if a message is PING, I would like to reset the timer.  If the timer ever goes off, the cache::empty_cache should be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::asio::io_service::run()` is a blocking call. In your specific case, you should avoid calling that in your main thread.

**Note**: In a typical async-driven app, you **should** build your app around the `run` method.

As for the timer code logic, something like that should work :

```
boost::asio::io_service service;
// Creates a work object to prevent the thread from exiting after the first job is done
boost::asio::io_service::work work(service);

// Creates the timer and post the aync wait now, will only start when service.run() is called
boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(service, boost::posix_time::seconds(60));
timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&cache::empty_cache, ...));

// Starts the worker thread to allow the timer to asynchronously waits
boost::thread ping_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &service));

while (true) // you should add a condition in order to leave if the timer expires
{
    std::string message = s_recv(subscriber);

    /**/ if (message == "UPDATE")
    {
        // Process update
    }
    else if (message == "PING")
    {
        // Cancel the current timer
        timer.cancel();
        // Start another async wait
        timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&cache::empty_cache, ...));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great, thank you so much, works like a charm.  I've updated my original post with the working code I ended up with in case someone needs it in the future.

Comment: Why would you want to avoid calling `.run` in your main thread? I'd say it's recommended: you just let asio take over your event loop for the main operation and if you need any non-asynchronous logic you put that in an additional thread.

Comment: @KillianDS I was talking in OP's specific case, since it didn't seem he was using async recv/send methods. I agree that he'd have been better that way, but that wouldn't answer the actual question. I've edited the answer to reflect that.